# Notifying a class of another class' changes

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Having the classes `Container`, `Item` and `Property`, the container shall be notified whenever a property in an item changes.

The container is the owner of the items and needs the information to properly manage them according to their properties.

I've thought of 2 options yet:

1. Observer pattern.
2. Proxy object.

The observer pattern seems to be too heavy for that task in my opinion. A proxy object could work out well, however in that case I'd violate the DRY principle, because I have to forward calls from the proxy to the actual object.

A requirement is that the details are hidden from the user. It's required that it's not needed to call some `update_item()` function or similar, i.e. giving the responsibility of informing the container to the user, which might lead to usage problems.

Answer (score 4):

In such simple case I don't see a reason of using `Observer`. Since an `Item` can be only in one container at once I would just go with giving the `Item` a reference or pointer to the container it is placed in.

When some `Property` of the `Item` changes it as able to notify it's `Container` via that pointer

`Observer` pattern is useful in case you need to notify many objects.

**EDIT**

Making every simple thing using Interfaces and extremely clean design may also harm you. I think the quote from `zen of Python` explains good what i mean:

```
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules. //make Interfaces
Although practicality beats purity. //but not everywhere
```

So you should a have balance between purity and practicality

Comment: The problem I see with that approach is that ``Item`` becomes dependent on ``Container``, and ``Container`` is dependent on ``Item``. This is not a problem with C++, but imho it signals a design flaw. Generally I tend to keep things isolated.

Comment: @Tank: You can make the communication via some `ContainterInterface` and `ItemInterface` or something like that if you want . It does not differ from making interfaces for Observer pattern. But try not to complicate the simple things )

Comment: It's the result of reading books like _Clean Code_ and others. ;) When ``Item`` gets dependent on ``Container``, I'd immediately recognize that in the unit test and to be honest it'd feel odd to have to deal with ``Container`` there. The interface idea sounds good to me, because it looses up the dependencies.

Comment: got it, thanks. I'm still somewhat undecided, because I'm afraid of those "Ah whatever, let's do it so that it works" decisions, if you know what I mean. It's kinda funny, complicated and bigger things are often easier to design than such little ones. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the pattern that is easiest to understand and maintain, and requires the least invention of specialized components. In the environment I work in (objective-C), the observer pattern is about as uncomplicated as it gets. It also offers flexibility when your notification requiements change.

Andrew's answer is event simpler - direct communication between objects does not requie the invention of a proxy or the overhead of notification handling. But it has less flexibility, should you need it in the future.

I'm not sure what "too heavy" means. Perhaps you can explain that.

Comment: "Too heavy" means what you actually described: The overhead of an observer pattern. And that for something that happens internally only (i.e. the user will never subscribe to the objects). The simplest solution I can think of is a proxy, but that's quite annoying because it duplicates code.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned before, an Observer is pretty much overkill here, but the solution is pretty simple.  You just need to "bubble up" the event.

- When a property is changed, it notifies it's parent item.
- When an item is changed (a side-affect from either a property changing, or something more integral to the item), it notifies it's container/parent).
- When a container is notified, well, you're done.  If containers can be nested then I guess it can raise an event to it's parent container if necessary.

Comment: Similar _problem_ to Andrew's suggestion: It will add hierarchical dependencies upwards. It's like a wheel having to know the car. ;)

Comment: @Tank, but in a *sense* the wheel doesn't need to know the car.  It just turns.  That is in, itself, an event.  Whether the car listens to the wheel turning or not, is irrelevant.  We just provide the mechanism for information to propagate. :)

Comment: that's true, however the wheel can also live without the car, ``Item`` couldn't live without ``Container`` – except you allow to have no parent, but that's normally not the case. Okay, enough of the car stupidity. ;)